# Under Lion, unable to log in with DisplayLink drivers installed

Tags: macos

I have a mid-2009 MBP 15", and I recently upgraded to lion.

I also have DisplayLink hardware which worked fine under SnowLeopard.

With Lion, as per http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1059, I am unable to log in, ever, once I install the DisplayLink drivers -- even if I have none of the DL hardware plugged in. I had to reinstall Lion to recover.

The forum thread suggests turning off 'automatic graphics switching' as a workaround.

I could flip that setting and then install the drivers and reboot again. If it doesn't work, however, it's another Lion install, which is quite time-consuming. Is there some mechanism I am missing that would allow me to recover my system more rapidly if the workaround is unhelpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login screen is not being drawn, however it is there. If you go ahead and type your user name, tab, password then press return you'll log in.

Alternatively you could boot in [safemode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455)

If you do turn off that graphics switching and, if applicable, go into energy saver and switch graphics from "Better battery life" to "Higher performance" most of the display bugs go away since it switches to using a different driver where these bugs don't seem to exist.

The downside is that our mbp's were not really designed to be high performance graphics crunching machines. They will get very hot when left in this mode. This is regardless of cpu load, whether or not you have the display link plugged in, or if even the driver is installed. It actually gets hot enough after just 15-20 minutes or so that it feels like its burning my lap and my palms get sweaty. The cooling on these just isn't setup to support high cpu or high gpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well.  However, I discovered that I WAS able to log in - the issue is the login prompt (and later some window content) was not displaying.

Once I plugged in the displayLink display, I was able to uninstall the driver.  However, the displayLink forum says this is due to a Lion issue with video drivers covered in this thread:  http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1059

So this needs to be address; I am out a display until this is fixed.